# Jailbreak and overclock ipad cpu

Tags: jailbreak, ipad-3

Its a pretty simple question. How can I jailbreak and overclock my Ipad 3rd gen. Apple has a system in place to down clock the cpu as the battery gets older. And its gotten pretty bad (20 minute load time on web pages and apps not functioning bad). I know that Ill have to tether it to a wall 24/7, but thats better that how it functions now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPad does not have the iOS throttle feature, only iPhones have them. But all smartphones and tablets have a hardware throttle feature. Your battery is the cause of the slowdown. The PMIC (internal host device) regulates voltages and clock signal generators. This is controlled by its own firmware separate from iOS, usually MaskROM (not modifiable). This prevents damage to the CPU, BaseBand processor etc. when you put load on a faulty battery, its supply voltage will drop during this peak load, leading to a crash or reboot. The PMIC is filtering this away, and in case of an bad battery, it has to lower performance to prefent crashes etc

Bottom line, you need a new battery. A electric car won't run as fast on a near empty battery as it would on a full battery